# C : Auto-complete file names matching a pattern in access() or execl() on unix / linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, system-calls

I am having a program `masterprog` that exec()s a binary matching a specific pattern amongst multiple such files `slaveprog.1.1.0`, `slaveprog.1.2.1`, `slaveprog.2.1.10`, ... within the same directory.

To be more clear, my `masterprog` checks for the environment in the system (in this case Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64) and looks for few more factors and decides which `slaveprog.X.Y.Z` to execute. My `slaveprog` naming convention is as follows:

- `X`: 1=debian | 2=rpm
- `Y`: 1=amd64 | 2=x86
- `Z`: latest slaveprog version

My master program is able to generate `slaveprog.1.1.` from the environment and calls:

```
access("./slaveprog.1.1.*",F_OK); // To verify if file exists
execl("/slaveprog.1.1.*","/slaveprog.1.1.*",NULL);
```

But unfortunately `access()` returns `-1` even if `slaveprog.1.1.3` exists in the current working directory.

Can anyone suggest me if there is any simpler way than to open the directory, list all files and select the appropriate file to achieve this?

Comment: Using wildcards, or *globbing* as it it called, is done by the *shell* and not the system calls. You need to do the globbing yourself. For this you can use e.g. [the `glob` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html).

Comment: you probably want `glob()`.

Comment: `*` is a meta-character for glob-pattern matching. The shell (e.g. bash) uses this when processing the command line. [`access()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/access) doesn't this but tries to access a file `./slaveprog.1.1.*` which cannot be found.

Comment: Another possible solution is simply to loop from zero to some max version number and call `access` until it fails. Then you know which version number is the highest.

Comment: Opening the directory and listing all files is exactly what `glob()` and the shell do internally when expanding `*`.

Comment: Note that you mistyped `"./slaveprog"` as `"/slaveprog"` in your exec call, and that `NULL` should be `(char *)NULL` there (to be compatible with systems that `#define NULL 0`).